# How to push a file made from a workflow GitHub Actions into another private repository of the same account?

Tags: r, github, github-actions, github-api

I would like to run the following code which has a csv file as output and save it into another private repository of my account.

In this way I can run the Workflow without the private repository threshold but still keeping the file private.

Here is my code

```
#FEEDER CHECKER

library(blastula)
library(tidyverse)
library(tibble)
library(openxlsx)
library(gdata)
library(lubridate)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(plyr)
library(polite)
library(xml2)
library(gt)
library(readr)

#######################################################################################################################################################################

URL_FEED_I <- Sys.getenv("URL_FEED_I")

xml_address <- URL_FEED_I

imetec_rss_xml <- as_list(read_xml(xml_address))

xml_df <- tibble::as_tibble(imetec_rss_xml) %>%
  unnest_longer(rss)



item_wider <- xml_df %>%
  dplyr::filter(rss_id == "item") %>%
  unnest_wider(rss)


lp_df <- item_wider %>%
  # 1st time unnest to release the 2-dimension list?
  unnest(cols = names(.)) %>%
  # 2nd time to nest the single list in each cell?
  unnest(cols = names(.)) %>%
  # convert data type
  readr::type_convert()

remove_special_categories <-
  lp_df %>% filter(product_type != "Black Friday")

remove_special_categories <-
  remove_special_categories %>% filter(product_type != "Pasqua")

remove_special_categories <-
  remove_special_categories %>% filter(product_type != is.na(product_type))


data <- Sys.time()
date <- week(Sys.Date())


subset_df <-
  remove_special_categories %>% select(title, availability, price, sale_price, brand, mpn)


subset_df <- subset_df[!duplicated(subset_df[c('mpn')]),]


subset_df$data <- data
subset_df$week <- date


subset_df$discount_percentage <- 0

subset_df <-
  subset_df %>% separate(price, c("price", "currency"), sep = " ")
subset_df <-
  subset_df %>% separate(sale_price, c("discount", "currency_2"), sep = " ")
subset_df <- subset_df %>% select(-currency,-currency_2)

##Remove the EUR and transform into numeric

subset_df$discount_percentage <-
  100 - (round((as.numeric(subset_df$discount) * 100) / as.numeric(subset_df$price)))

colnames(subset_df)[1] <- "Product Name"
colnames(subset_df)[2] <- "Availability"
colnames(subset_df)[3] <- "Original Price"
colnames(subset_df)[4] <- "Discounted Price"
colnames(subset_df)[5] <- "Brand"
colnames(subset_df)[6] <- "SKU"
colnames(subset_df)[7] <- "Time of Logging"
colnames(subset_df)[8] <- "Week of the Year"
colnames(subset_df)[9] <- "Discount Percentage"


subset_df <- subset_df[, c(1, 6, 2, 3, 4, 9, 7, 8, 5)]


######################################################################################################################################################################

#Export the file 

write.csv(subset_df,
          file = paste0("imetec/ecommerce_tracker_", data, ".csv"))
```

And this is the yml file

```
# Hourly scraping
name: Feeder Tracker Imetec

# Controls when the action will run.
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 */6 * * *'

jobs:
  autoscrape:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: macos-latest

    # Load repo and install R
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@master

    # Set-up R
    - name: Install packages
      run: |
        R -e 'install.packages("tidyverse")'
        R -e 'install.packages("tibble")'
        R -e 'install.packages("openxlsx")'
        R -e 'install.packages("gdata")'
        R -e 'install.packages("lubridate")'
        R -e 'install.packages("rvest")'
        R -e 'install.packages("stringr")'
        R -e 'install.packages("dplyr")'
        R -e 'install.packages("purrr")'
        R -e 'install.packages("plyr")'
        R -e 'install.packages("polite")'
        R -e 'install.packages("xml2")'
        R -e 'install.packages("gt")'
        R -e 'install.packages("blastula")'
        R -e 'install.packages("readr")'
            
    # Run R script
    - name: Get the Feed, Process It and Store It for further use
      env:
          URL_FEED_IMETEC : ${{ secrets.URL_FEED_IMETEC  }}

      
      run: Rscript imetec_feed_tracker.R

    # Add new files in data folder, commit along with other modified files, push
    - name: Commit files
      run: |
        git config --local user.name github-actions
        git config --local user.email "actions@github.com"
        git add imetec/*
        git commit -am "GH ACTION Autorun IMETEC FEEDER TRACKER LAST RUN $(date)"
        git push origin main --force
      env:
        REPO_KEY: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
        username: github-actions
```

I have found this https://github.com/marketplace/actions/push-a-file-to-another-repository

but I'm not quite sure how to integrate it into my yml file except to add my github api token as secret

```
name: Push File

on: push

jobs:
  copy-file:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Pushes test file
      uses: dmnemec/copy_file_to_another_repo_action@main
      env:
        API_TOKEN_GITHUB: ${{ secrets.API_TOKEN_GITHUB }}
      with:
        source_file: 'test2.md'
        destination_repo: 'dmnemec/release-test'
        destination_folder: 'test-dir'
        user_email: 'example@email.com'
        user_name: 'dmnemec'
        commit_message: 'A custom message for the commit'
```

How do I integrate this last piece into my main yml code?

Comment: You would just have to substitute your `Commit files` step in your current workflow by the `Pushes test files` step your shared as example.